# How to group fields having same data using basic command

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I am new to Ubuntu. So please tolerate me if it is a silly question.

My fields are:

```
Ritesh:Nair:IT:58
Saylee:Domki:IT:62
Monica:Shinde:IT:69
Mahesh:Nair:EXTC:53
Arun:Nair:EXTC:64
```

I wanted the output something like this:

```
IT 3
EXTC 2
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that those fields are stored in a file, let's call it 'file.txt', you can use the following command:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F":" '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```